How to Federate Service Accounts from an External IdP in Keycloak?
We are currently able to federate users from an external IdP in Keycloak. The external IdP also has some service accounts set up with secret-based authentication.
However, we do not see an option to link an external IdP to a Keycloak service account (client). The idea is that the credentials of the service account will be owned and managed by the external IdP, and we want to use the service account to access resources under Keycloak.
How can we federate these service accounts from the external IdP into Keycloak?
